# How to create child parent relationship from unorganized table?

Tags: sql

I have a table where data is stored in the form sku's. This table is used to stored sku's with its similar sku's. For eg. I have a ring which have different types. So this table stores the combination of simliar types of rings as it comes in the production.

Now, **I have a problem to distingusih which sku will be the parent** or which **sku** needs to the child.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Can you explain a little more.  Why did you circle some but not all -- practically all of your numbers are in both columns...

Comment: I circled some for examples and for understanding .there is scenrio where Item can only used as child or parent and same for SIMI_ItemCode means from both coulms any one can be parent or child.

Comment: Well its up to you whether a number should be parent or child, better check your requirements for that. To me this seems like a recursive function to generate a treelike structure like a family tree.

Comment: Yes It is like that . Main Problem is that our table is initially maintained similar items of items, so there is no issue with these types of records. Now  I have a requirement to make parent-child relationship. 
Previously records are stored in inconsistent manner. That's why all the problems arises.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT parent.Item, child.similarItem 
FROM temp parent 
FULL JOIN temp child 
ON parent.Item = child.similarItem
```

This selects all parent-child pairs. `257074` will be returned as both a parent and a child and is thus present in two rows. In case this is not what you're expecting as a result, please state what you ARE expecting.

## Edit:

**Your table is a bit unclear (to me)**

```
Row 11: ( Item = `257074`, SimilarItem = `228725` )
Row 12: ( Item = `228725`, SimilarItem = `257074` )
```

Based on what are you stating that `257074` has `Isparent = 1` in row `9` of the expected result? Why not `228725` instead (since they both reference each other)?

**I think you should start by not referencing the relationship both ways**

Example given:

```
ID Parent Item
0  NULL   1
1  NULL   2
2  1      3
3  3      4
4  NULL   5
5  3      6
```

Which is this tree:

```
  1    2    5
  |
  3
  |
+-+-+
4   6
```

This would result in:

```
SELECT Item AS SKU,
       CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT ID FROM temp WHERE Parent = table.Item )
           THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END AS IsParent,
       Parent AS ParentSKU
FROM   temp table

SKU IsParent ParentSKU
----------------------
1   1        NULL
2   0        NULL
3   1        1
4   0        3
5   0        NULL
6   0        3
```

Note that the table I've provided is not referencing the parent-child-relationship both ways, though I'm still able to get the result you're asking for. Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Please check question again. Now i am provided u with expected result

Comment: But `555781` IS a parent..?

Comment: NO, 555781 is a child of 230639

Comment: @user1001101 I've extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for Reply. but according to this query, Parent can be child of same SKU. But i want to eliminate this scenrio and any possible combination should appear only Once. link italic bold code for Eg., 

**230639 1 555781**,
**230639 1 546381**,
**555781 1 230639**,
**546381 1 230639**

 When u run the query provided by me , You will get this point.

Comment: So you're saying that `Item` is not a unique value? In that case `ORDER BY Item` would fix your problem. As to the parent and child having the same number, that should be covered while inserting instead of fixing when selecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    m1.item as 'PARTENT',
    m2.similaritem as 'CHILD'
FROM temp m1 
full join temp m2 on m1.item = m2.similaritem
```

This will output results in the form of parent-child relationships

Comment: This query created a relationship where two items are treated as a parent and child of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parent-child relationship by simply adding a foreign key addressing this same table columns, similarItem-item.